Need clarification on using http client
I am using DI in client application and calling a library class in which I am calling external apis using httpclient. This httpclient object which is created from DI passing to library class. When I checked internet I have seen code where the SendAsync method is called in using. like below
 using(var response = httpClient.SendAsync(url))
 {
 }


I am having a question here is the lifetime of the httpclient object is decided by DI. So what is the use of calling httpclient.SendAsync in using statement?

Hi ,The correct pattern is to keep HttpClient managed by DI but dispose of the HttpResponseMessage after processing it, ensuring that any open connections or other unmanaged resources are released.

The using statement around the HttpClient.SendAsync call is not for the HttpClient itselfit's for the HttpResponseMessage that is returned by SendAsync

HttpClient should be added as singleton and lifecycle should be managed by DI. As Abaiz mentioned above the disposable statement is for sendasyc method and not for http client

The statement of @WaqasAziz is not completely correct, because registering HttpClient as a singleton can cause problems (most noticeably, any changes to a DNS will not be reflected in a singleton HttpClient). For this reason, Microsoft introduced the IHttpClientFactory and the .AddHttpClient extension method, which uses the IHttpClientFactory in the background. Best practice, therefore, is to use the factory and the AddHttpClient extension method and not to register HttpClient as a singleton.

Hi, Thanks for the answers. I am using winforms application (dotnet framework 4.8 )and cannot use DI. So what I have done is creating a httpclient object and passing to all the services so that single object will be used but sometimes I am getting error like
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
